# Unit test a call to function of instance variable

Tags: c++, unit-testing, misra

I have some C++ code similar to the example given below. I would like to write a unit test to verify that mFlashLamp.trigger is called exactly five times. 
However, up to now I was not able to figure out a good way to do this.

I have the following restraints: 
Compliance to Misra / GoogleTest / GoogleMock

```
include <iostream>

class FlashLamp
{
public:
    virtual void trigger(){
        std::cout << "Trigger FlashLamp" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Spectrometer
{
public:
    FlashLamp mFlashLamp;

    void foo(){
        for( int i=0; i<5; i++ ){
            mFlashLamp.trigger();
        }
    }

};

int main(){
    Spectrometer S;
    S.foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Does anybody have a good and clean solution for a unit test. 
One solution I can think of is to

```
class Spectrometer
{
public:
    FlashLamp mFlashLamp;
    FlashLamp* pFlashLamp;
}
```

have an additional pointer to the instance variable and use this to access the trigger. But this would mean some code bloat as it requires a null pointer check on every dereference. 
Does anybody have an idea for a better solution.

PS: 
I really tried to come up with a good title but couldn't. If someone has any improvements please feel free to edit it.

Comment: It's a bit unclear, what you want to test actually. Do you want to ensure that a number of calls to `trigger()` is made from the `Spectrometer` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idiomatic way in *unit testing* is to use *interfaces* and *Mock Classes*:

```
#include <iostream>

// The interface definition
struct IFlashLamp {
    virtual ~IFlashLamp() {}
    virtual void trigger() = 0;
};

class FlashLamp : public IFlashLamp 
{
public:
    virtual void trigger() override {
        std::cout << "Trigger FlashLamp" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Spectrometer
{
public:
    IFlashLamp& mFlashLamp;

    Spectrometer(IFlashlamp& flashLamp) : mFlashLamp(flashLamp) {}
    void foo(){
        for( int i=0; i<5; i++ ){
            mFlashLamp.trigger();
        }
    }

};
```

---

You'll implement the interface with a mock class, that allows you to inspect the expectations regarding calls to the interface:

```
class FlashLampMock : public IFlashlamp {
    int triggerCallCounter;
public:
    FlashLampMock() : triggerCallCounter(0) {}
    virtual void trigger() override {
        ++triggerCallCounter;
    }
    int getTriggerCallCounter() const { return triggerCallCounter; }
};
```

---

This is the unit test then:

```
int main(){
    FlashLampMock flashLampMock;
    Spectrometer S(FlashLampMock);
    S.foo();
    assert(flashLampMock.getTriggerCallCounter() == 5);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for giving the full solution as an example. I wanted to avoid passing in the FlashLamp, because in the real system there are many more components so I did not think in this direction. 
However your solution is so good, that I think I just need to create a compound object with all the components and pass this in.